# How to detect the item has been dropped in the same sortable list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two connected sortable lists. My code works fine for when I drag one element from the list on the left side to the one on the right side, but can you tell me what event should I be looking for if I want to know the order of items in the left list when an item gets dragged and dropped in the same list (basically reorder the items in the same list, not dragging and dropping to the other list but to the same).

Thank you.

**Edit:**

Here is the link to the code: http://jsfiddle.net/Hitman666/WEa3g/1/

So, as you will see I have an alert when items are dragged and dropped in oposite lists, but I need an event also for when the list (for example the green one) gets reordered. Then I would need to alert the order, for example: `4,3,2,1`

HTML:

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <li>Item 5</li>    
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>    
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#sortable1, #sortable2 { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; float: left; margin-right: 10px; }
#sortable1 li, #sortable2 li { margin: 0 5px 5px 5px; padding: 5px; font-size: 1.2em; width: 120px; }

#sortable1 li{background: green;}
#sortable2 li{background: yellow;}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        receive: myFunc
    }).disableSelection();

    function myFunc(event, ui) {
        alert(ui.item.html());
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you post some code, or a link?

Comment: @Alex: I've updated my post with the code link on jsfiddle

Comment: I have edited your linked jsfiddle code into your question. It's always a good idea, so your question could still be useful to the community after your linked code gets removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the update event. Here is my example (notice that I made 2 extra function calls to sort since you needed the evt only on the left list):

```
$(function(){
    $( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        update: myFunc
    });

    $( "#sortable2" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",  // deactivate:myFunc
    });

    function myFunc(event, ui){
        var b = $("#sortable1 li"); // array of sorted elems
        for (var i = 0, a = ""; i < b.length; i++)
        {
            var j=i+1; // an increasing num.
            a = a + j + ") " + $(b[i]).html() + '\n ' //putting together the items in order
        }
        alert(a)                 
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, but the problem is I already have (in my production code) a function for receive event in the left list. So then I would would have two events, which I was hoping to somehow get arround.. Hmm, any ideas? So I do need the receive event to know that I received an item from another connected list, but now I need an event which will fire only when i pick up an element from left list and drop it in the same list just on another place. Hope I'm making sense...

Comment: @Nikola: you can still use only the update event and look for the ui.sender try by adding the following code just above the alert in the prev example,
    'if(ui.sender)
  {
   a=a+"\n"+"you added '"+ui.item.html()+"' from another other list"}'

Comment: hmmm, seems to me i have yet another problem: since i have two lists and the first one now has a update event which checks for ui.sender and therefor behaves as the receive event, I also have a receive event in the second list which fires wen it receives and item from the first list. My problem remains this: what if i drag an item out from its place in first list and place it in the same (first) list jut on some other position - how to detect this event?? Cause I can't have an 'else' statement in if(ui.sender) because here in else we can have two cases: the item just reordered, or

Comment: [continuing my comment] - or the item taken from list one and put into list two. You see my problem- i really need to know the event at least for "remove" so i would have (on update event) cases for receive, remove and simple reorder. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

use this drag and drop js to do this and

http://www.redips.net/javascript/drag-and-drop-table-content/

and it has lots of events on which you can write your js code or calling server side code by using ajax..

i.e.

```
REDIPS.drag.myhandler_clicked = function () { }
REDIPS.drag.myhandler_moved = function () { document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Element is moved' }
REDIPS.drag.myhandler_notmoved = function () { document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Element is not moved' }
REDIPS.drag.myhandler_dropped = function () { document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Element is dropped' }
```